# How to pass an id and echo same id in the same page in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a div with the id of a user when the username is click, what I really want is to echo that div in desame page where the username is click. For instance in facebook when you click a username of a friend it will echo a div or form with the name of the user at the top so how can I archive that. I link the id to the div because if I want it to echo in another page I will like it to that page but that is not I actually want to do, so please someone should help and fix my code it's a mess right now.

```
<div class="friend_list">
       <div id="list">

          <?php

             $list = "select friend_uid,friend_id from friend where user_id='$id' AND status='1'";
             $friend = mysqli_query($conn,$list);
             while($rowf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend)){


             ?>
             <div id="f_list">
             <a href="#idm?id=<?php echo $rowf['friend_id'].'<br>'; ?>">
             <?php echo $rowf['friend_uid'].'<br>'; ?></a></div>
             <?php
             }
              $friend_list = "select user_uid,user_id from friend where friend_id='$id'  AND  status='1'";
             $res_friend = mysqli_query($conn,$friend_list);

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_friend)){


             ?>
             <div id="f_list">
             <a href="#idm?id=<?php echo $row['user_id'].'<br>'; ?>">
             <?php echo $row['user_uid'].'<br>'; ?></a></div>
             <?php
             }

             ?>
           <input type="text" placeholder="search for a friend">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="idm">
    <?php


}
 if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   echo '<div class="chat">'.$_GET[ "id"].'</div>';

   }
?>
```

Comment: warning : `xss` .

Comment: Do you mean hover

Comment: no when the username is click

Comment: You want to load user data on click of user name & display username at the top of data.. am i right..?

Comment: yes sir that exactly what i want to echo the id or the username if the username is click.Because am trying to build a chat system and i want if the name of a friend is click a div with the friend name will be echo in the same page where the name is click like that of facebook.